# Code doesn't run after packaging with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I created a code using robobrowser to check website status and log that into a file, and mail if the HTTP Response is anything else than 400.

Later I had to add Pypac, since my systems are behind a proxy.

Rest of the code works after packaging. I have tried in different machines(which aren't behind proxies)

As soon as I add the proxy the packaged `.exe` stops working.

I have tried to add 'pypac' in Hidden Imports as well.

```py
from pypac import PACSession
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser


session = PACSession()
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True, session=session)
```

Since the proxy part is not working.

**It is throwing errors like:**

> "urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

When I run the same code using python. There's no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just redid a small code with just PyPac and package it with Pyinstaller with console=True.

The returned error was

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\CHOWDH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI199722\tld\res\effective_tld_names.dat.txt'

So while packaging I added the data using the spec file *C:\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\tld\res*

[Spec File Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHoV6.png)

datas=[('C:\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\tld\res\effective_tld_names.dat.txt', 'tld\res')]